# Adding template anchor at runtime for dynamic components

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a component dynamically at runtime and specify **where** it should be inserted dynamically. So for I've found loads of tutorials and examples of how to create a component at runtime, but they all require an anchor to be in the template. That means, I can't decide **where** the component is added to the DOM.

I've tried using @ViewChildren to find dynamically inserted anchors, but that doesn't seem to work:

`@ViewChildren("marker") markers:QueryList<Marker>;
$("container").append("<marker #marker />");`

Specifically, I'm using Leaflet which allows you to place markers on a map. You can pass Leaflet an html template for the markers. Instead of static html, I'd like to be able to use a component for the markers, because they will become quite complicated in the future.

Comment: You can't manipulate DOM in this way.

Comment: It's impossible to dynamically choose where to insert a component?

Comment: You are doing it behind the angular.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it not "behind" Angular?